# how do container queries / contain property make my container disappear

Tags: html, css, flexbox, container-queries

Could you explain what makes my pictures disappear ?

```css
  span,
  figure {
    container-type: inline-size;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 10%;
    float: right;
  }
  .image img {
    max-height: 500px;
    height: max-content;
    width: max-content;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <figure class="image">
      <img src="https://www.power-corpus.de/storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.power-corpus.de%2FWebRoot%2FHostEurope2%2FShops%2Fes10619609%2F60C7%2F4821%2F28B4%2F6E8F%2F776F%2F50ED%2F8963%2F9690%2FCitrulline-SFD.jpg&shop=es10619609&width=600&height=2560" loading="lazy" />
    </figure>
    <p>
      <span class="image ">
        <img src="https://www.power-corpus.de/storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.power-corpus.de%2FWebRoot%2FHostEurope2%2FShops%2Fes10619609%2F60C7%2F4821%2F28B4%2F6E8F%2F776F%2F50ED%2F8963%2F9690%2FCitrulline-SFD.jpg&shop=es10619609&width=600&height=2560" loading="lazy" /></span>
      <span class="image ">
        <img src="https://www.power-corpus.de/storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.power-corpus.de%2FWebRoot%2FHostEurope2%2FShops%2Fes10619609%2F60C7%2F4821%2F28B4%2F6E8F%2F776F%2F50ED%2F8963%2F9690%2FCitrulline-SFD.jpg&shop=es10619609&width=600&height=2560" loading="lazy" /></span>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I wanted to use a container query to know the size of figure or img, and change the layout if they're too small (since they normally share the container width with other images too).
But any container-type property whose value is not "normal" just makes the elements disappear. huh ??
I don't understand how that works.

Comment: Posting your HTML and CSS into a [Stackoverflow snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) would be helpful. We could see it, test it and even answer by changing it.

Comment: you can play with this: codepen.io/Mehdi-Saada/pen/dygyVNz formatted css etc, really cool tool I must say !
These img elemenst are not responsive, they're plain img contained by figures.
container properties still make them disappear.

Comment: Good that you have added your code with images on available URLs. It would have been great to use the Stackoverflow snippet like mentionned instead of mixing HTML and CSS together. To get links working to codepen.io, add the `https://` in front of it. In codepen, don't put `<html> ... <body>` as you only have to put the content of the body (codepen notices you that, by the way). If you remove `container-type: inline-size` your images appear again. Better explain what you are trying to achieve visually, for both cases (as block and as inline content).

Comment: Why so complicated URL's to images? `https://www.power-corpus.de/WebRoot/HostEurope2/Shops/es10619609/60C7/4821/28B4/6E8F/776F/50ED/8963/9690/Citrulline-SFD.jpg` would be way more simple. Better use images from [Unsplash](https://unsplash.com/) as you can pass the resolution in the URLs and achieve your initial use of the `srcset` attribute for having multiple resolutions.

Comment: I merely copied-pasted urls from internet. My own code is quite different but I removed all the unrelated stuff. First I wish to know why `container-type:size` does what it does here.
My goal was to enlarge the pictures whenever they get their display size get too small.
So something like that:


.image {container: image / inline-size;}
@container image (width < 40px) {
      max-width:unset !important;
      img {max-height: unset important}
}

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem is because you are using **both** flexbox and `float`.  Remove `float: right;` from your code and use the proper flexbox way to align your items to the right.

I don't know what goal you are trying to achieve in the end, so it's hard to know what to suggest here for how to better align these images

Answer (score 1):

`float:right` as it was has hidden the element. I have played around it and moved `float:right` to the `img` rather than its container, like this:

```css
span,
  figure {
    container-type: inline-size;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 10%;
  }
  figure {
      margin-left: 80%;
  }
  .image img {
    max-height: 500px;
    height: max-content;
    width: max-content;
    max-width: 100%;
    float: right;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <figure class="image">
      <img src="https://www.power-corpus.de/storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.power-corpus.de%2FWebRoot%2FHostEurope2%2FShops%2Fes10619609%2F60C7%2F4821%2F28B4%2F6E8F%2F776F%2F50ED%2F8963%2F9690%2FCitrulline-SFD.jpg&shop=es10619609&width=600&height=2560" loading="lazy" />
    </figure>
    <p>
      <span class="image ">
        <img src="https://www.power-corpus.de/storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.power-corpus.de%2FWebRoot%2FHostEurope2%2FShops%2Fes10619609%2F60C7%2F4821%2F28B4%2F6E8F%2F776F%2F50ED%2F8963%2F9690%2FCitrulline-SFD.jpg&shop=es10619609&width=600&height=2560" loading="lazy" /></span>
      <span class="image ">
        <img src="https://www.power-corpus.de/storage/images/image?remote=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.power-corpus.de%2FWebRoot%2FHostEurope2%2FShops%2Fes10619609%2F60C7%2F4821%2F28B4%2F6E8F%2F776F%2F50ED%2F8963%2F9690%2FCitrulline-SFD.jpg&shop=es10619609&width=600&height=2560" loading="lazy" /></span>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't use this and don't understand. I need <figure> because I have <figcaption> too, and this won't floats at the same place as it should. That's why flex and flex-direction:column was so practical.
If I float the img only, the captions won't follow and place themselves in the center of the image's axis... It won't appear "contained" by the figure element whatsoever.

Comment: @MehdiSaada your main problem is that the images disappear. As about your exact goal, you have not provided too much information. So, my answer shows you a way that your image appears on the screen after all and both `p` and `figure` are gravitating towards the right edge of the screen. I understand that the current answer does not match your exact criteria, but, to be frank, it's unsurprising, given the fact that you did not explain your exact expectations, so it is difficult to meet an expectation you did not share, isn't it?

Comment: Ok, ok.
I want structures like <figure><figcaption>blabla</figcaption><img></figure> to float as a whole on the right, with figcaptions on top of the img, centered on the inline axis, both centered on their inline axis.
Right now, I have that, with this code:
.image{
 clear:right;
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:column;
 max-width:50%;
 width:fit-content;
 img{max-height:500px;width:max-content;max-width:100%;margin:auto;}
 float:right;
 a {display:contents}}

and it has to float on the right.

Comment: But I also want to dynamically set "max-width:unset" whenever the effective size gets below a certain threshold.
and since I don't want any javascript, I thought I could do that with a CSS container query, to query the size of the figure element which contains <img>.
I hope I explained well.

Comment: @MehdiSaada what effective size are we speaking about? Is it the size of the viewport or some element? You can use CSS media queries to have the conditional and `calc` to perform a calculation.

Comment: I want each individual .images element to receive the property maw-width:unset whenever their display gets inferior to say, 200 px. Is this possible with container-queries or not ?

Comment: @MehdiSaada have you tried with something like `@container (max-width: 200px) {`?

Comment: I can't, all elements with .image disappear whenever I give them a container property, and I still don't know why !